# Re-authentication with biometrics in a mobile app using access token

Tags: mobile, oauth2, biometrics, access-token

My mobile app has this (fairly common) authentication user experience:

1. user signs in with email and password
2. user is prompted to enable biometrics for faster access next time
3. when user returns to app after a time of inactivity

   1. if they enabled biometrics, they are given the biometric challenge and then granted full access to the app
   2. if they did *not* enable biometrics, they need to log in again with email and password
4. if user chooses to explicitly log out, then next time they are treated as a new user (go to point 1)

I'm stuck on how to securely implement step 3.1.

My app is written in React Native and using Auth0 for authentication. The only decent biometrics library I can find is [react-native-biometrics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-biometrics). There's a diagram in the docs illustrating the intended use, but to briefly summarise:

1. When enabling biometrics, app generates a key pair on device
2. App registers the public key with the backend
3. When a user returns to the app, app prompts for biometrics
4. App sends a signed payload to the backend
5. Backend verifies signature using stored public key

So far so good, but what happens next? Once the user has successfully passed biometric authentication, how to I make them signed in on the device? I had thought of storing the user's refresh token on the server and returning that in point 5 above, but that amounts to storing unhashed credentials on the server, which is obviously not OK.

Am I thinking about this right? Do I need to find some way to mint a new access/refresh token?

Comment: My first thought would be to encrypt the user's refresh token using the key stored on the device.  Then you can use biometrics to retrieve the key from the device keystore, decrypt the refresh token, and exchange it for a new access token.  No idea if react-native-biometrics would support that flow though.

Comment: That makes sense but unfortunately that library only supports signing, not encrypting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-app biometric authentication should be cryptographically bound to the key use so that even if the attacker compromises the app, he won't be able to use the key without passing system backed in-app biometric authentication. To achieve this, your app should use [Android Keystore system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore).

### [Generate A New Secret Key](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#GeneratingANewPrivateKey)

This will be stored by **Trusted Execution Environment** (TEE) and will not be accessible to the app. Set the purpose of the key as [PURPOSE_ENCRYPT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProperties#PURPOSE_ENCRYPT) and [PURPOSE_DECRYPT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProperties#PURPOSE_DECRYPT) in [KeyProperties](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProperties).

### [Require User Authentication For Key Use](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#UserAuthentication)

[`setUserAuthenticationRequired`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)) API sets whether this key is authorized to be used only if the user has been authenticated.

### [Set User Authentication Parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationParameters(int,%20int))

`setUserAuthenticationParameters` sets the duration of time (seconds) and authorization type for which this key is authorized to be used after the user is successfully authenticated.

### [Show A Biometric Authentication Dialog](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth)

#### [Authenticate Using Either Biometric Or Lock Screen Credentials](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#biometric-or-lock-screen)

Although you can [authenticate using only biometric credentials](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#biometric-only), also allowing lock screen credentials can be used as a fallback if the biometric sensor fails.

### How The Key Is Used?

Once the user is authenticated, by using this key TEE will encrypt and decrypt the access and refresh tokens of the app within the specified duration of time in which the key is authorized to be used until next re-authentication schedule. As long as the access token is alive, let the app to use it and refresh it once it is expired. If the user has not enrolled biometrics or if the user has removed them, this is where the fallback to device credentials will be used. There is no need to prompt the user to login again until the user is no longer using the app from some time.

You can also protect sensitive user data in your app that you want to keep encrypted while the device is locked by using [setUnlockedDeviceRequired](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUnlockedDeviceRequired(boolean)).

> Sets whether the keystore requires the screen to be unlocked before allowing decryption using this key. If this is set to `true`, any attempt to decrypt or sign using this key while the screen is locked will fail. A locked device requires a PIN, password, biometric, or other trusted factor to access. While the screen is locked, any associated public key can still be used (e.g for signature verification).

---

There are similar APIs in iOS that achieves the exact same security design but I'm not aware of its implementation details.

Comment: This flow sounds good. Unfortunately the current version of `react-native-biometrics` doesn't support encryption (only signing) but [there is a PR](https://github.com/SelfLender/react-native-biometrics/pull/229).